# DTD root element

Tags: xml, root, dtd

Is it possible to define which element will be the root element in a DTD internally. In other words, Is it possible to define the root element when DTD is in a separate file?

Comment: When you say "internally" do you mean in a file that does not include the DTD?

Comment: normally you write a dtd in a separate file and before you write the xml document (another file) you say <!DOCTYPE "root-element" "dtd-url">. My question is: is there another way of specifying the root element within the dtd file?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Knowing why would make this question more useful to others, and may also help us suggest another way to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root element is determined by the `DOCTYPE` declaration. The root element can be any element in the DTD.

For example in the DTD below (test.dtd), `book` would normally be the root element:

```
<!ELEMENT book (chapter+)>
<!ELEMENT chapter (section+)>
<!ELEMENT section EMPTY>
```

However, if we use `section` in the doctype, `section` is the root element:

```
<!DOCTYPE section SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<section/>
```

I've used `DOCTYPE` declarations in the external DTD to directly specify the root element, but I don't think that is allowed by the spec. What I did was keep the `DOCTYPE` in the external DTD and remove the `DOCTYPE` from the XML file. I was able to associate the DTD with the XML file on the command line of the program I was using.